# Python list of classes issue

Tags: python, list, class

I'm running into trouble with some Python stuff. I have a list that has seven copies of a class and I am intending to change just the values of one of them but whenever I do it changes the value for all.

Here is the class:

```
class Node:
  previous = -1
  distFromSrc = 1000000
  visited = False
```

And here is how I create the list:

```
def createNodeTable(network):
  nodeTable = []
  for line in network:
    nodeTable.append(Node)
  return nodeTable
```

'network' is a list of length 7 so when I print the 'nodeTable[x].visited' before I attempt to make any changes to the values I get 'False' for every one.

If I call the following function however all of the '.visited' values change to false not just the one I am intending to change.

Whatever 'currentNode' is changed to I get the same issue:

```
def setVisited(currentNode, nodeTable):
  nodeTable[currentNode].visited = True
  return nodeTable
```

Is there an issue with the setVisited function or is it to with the nodeTable? I don't even know where to start to try to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nodeTable.append(Node)
```

The problem lies in that line. What you are doing there is that you append the *type* (or *class*) to the list. So you end up with a list of seven times the *exact same* type reference.

What you should do instead is creating instances of said type. You can do that by calling it.

```
nodeTable.append(Node())
```

Answer (score 2):

In this code, you are appending the exact same object, the class `Node`, in each iteration:

```
def createNodeTable(network):
  nodeTable = []
  for line in network:
    nodeTable.append(Node)
  return nodeTable
```

Because it is the exact same object, changing it changes it.

One presumes that you want to replace `nodeTable.append(Node)` with `nodeTable.append(Node())`

While you're at it, switch to new-style classes (assuming this is Python 2).

Incidentally, you can do this:

```
def createNodeTable(network):
    return [Node() for line in network]
```

Answer (score 2):

should't

```
def createNodeTable(network):
    nodeTable = []
    for line in network:
        nodeTable.append(Node)
   return nodeTable
```

be:

```
def createNodeTable(network):
    nodeTable = []
    for line in network:
        nodeTable.append(Node())
    return nodeTable
```

You want 7 different instances appended to nodeTable, not the same class object 7 times.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it would probably make more sense to have a list of instances of `Node` here.  If you really wanted to have a list of separate classes, you could use a class factory:

```
def make_node_class():
    class Node:
        previous = -1
        distFromSrc = 1000000
        visited = False
    return Node

node_table = [make_node_class() for line in network]
```

Each element of `node_table` is now a completely separate class, and setting `node_table[0].visited = True` will  not affect the value of `node_table[1].visited`.  This is unlikely to be a very sensible design, however.